# Page scans not including full load after api call

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am trying to scan my page and take screenshots. It works fine when done locally.

But when I deploy the `node js` app which uses `Playwright`, it seems to only take screenshot for the skeleton of the page.

It didn't wait for the whole page to load up. Page loads after an api call. At most takes 3 seconds.

This is what I initially tried which gives skeleton page. So it didn't wait for api call.

```
const proxy = {
  server: 'proxy.example.com:8080',
  bypass: '*.example.com',
};

const browser = await chromium.launch({
  proxy,
  headless: true,
});

const context = await browser.newContext({
  bypassCSP: true,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});

const page = await context.newPage();
await page.setDefaultTimeout(120000);
// getting eval not found error without this script. Doubt related to issue.
const evalInitScript = { content: 'Object.defineProperty(window, "eval", { writable: false })' }; 
await page.addInitScript(evalInitScript);

await page.goto('https://example.com', { waitUntil: 'networkidle' });
await page.screenshot({ path: screenshotPath, fullPage: true });
```

Thought to modify it and wait for a selector instead. Which means the api call completed and view did load.

This selector definitely exists. Plus this works locally.

```
// so tr element with a class called gray-02-bg. 
// There will be more than 1. As long as 1 found is fine.
await page.waitForSelector('tr.gray-02-bg');
```

But when I do this, no screenshots. It waits and throws following error.

> page.waitForSelector: Timeout 120000ms exceeded.
> =========================== logs =========================== waiting for locator('tr.gray-02-bg') to be visible name: 'TimeoutError'

But why?

I clearly reached the page since can still take screenshots of the skeleton page. (so can see some details).

Thus not a firewall issue.

Why does it seems like the page doesn't fully load and unable to find the element?

The api call would have taken at most 3 seconds.

P.S: The page being scanned is a React application page.

Comment: Can you share the site or a [mcve] of its behavior? I assume example.com is used as a placeholder, not the actual site. If it's not your site, is it detecting and blocking your bot?